# Laravel Project in subfolder reroutes to main domain. Is the setup right and how to add prefixes?

Tags: php, laravel, server, subdomain

For the testing of a new version of a project, I have to deploy a laravel project to a sub folder which was set up for me. I already programmed it on the localhost and only need to upload it.

The subdomain is on example.com/new

The structure I found in  Filezilla was like this:

(I do not have access/can't see to the main Versions files-does this mean it is a subdomain?)

- htacess
- env
- newProject(folder)

  - public

I did not have permission to upload new files above the public folder. The .env and .htacess could be replaced. So I did the following:

- htacess
- env
- newProject(folder)

  - public

    - index
    - project(folder)
      (laravel put another.env and .htacess in here are these the right ones to change)

      - .htacess
      - .env
      - rest of laravel files

Out of confusion I always just make a change in both existing .env's and .htacess because I don't know which is the right one. Is this setup right?   I already changed the index

```
require __DIR__.'/project/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/project/bootstrap/app.php';
```

My htacess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    [[rewritebase /new

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**MY PROBLEM:**
There is at least something working. Because I have an automatic rerouting for languages in the web.php

```
Route::redirect('/', '/en');
Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}', ''], function (){
...routes
```

And when I go to example.com/new it reroutes me to example.com/en instead of example.com/new/en. That means it does come to the routing part, dies this mean htacess and .env are set up right?

the error is of course

*"Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server."*

**MY QUESTION**

How do I stop the rerouting to /en and go to /new/en. Is there a prefix I can add to all my routes. And can I be sure the rest is set up right just because the code routes to /en which is set up in the web.php?

Comment: I think you are trying to do something too complex, I would recommend you to create just one project and using `Route::group` to add "sub-domains" to your webpage. Another alternative could be modifying the apache file adding the `Alias` tag, in that way, you could have two project sharing the same path but they are different.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the Route::group part? This is a project from work and my boss set it up this way so i guess there is no way around it.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `Route::prefix`, you can take a look in the official documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-group-prefixes